# Getting date value as NAN in safari using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, safari

I am getting this issue while comparing some date using Javascript. I am getting this issue in only on `Safari`. Its working fine on `Chrome`. Let me to explain my code first.

```
var date='2016-05-21';
var to='2016-05-23';
var eventdate='2016-06-01 16:48:51';
function getMidnight(date) {
    return (new Date(new Date(date.replace(/-/g, "/")).getFullYear(), new Date(date.replace(/-/g, "/")).getMonth(), new Date(date.replace(/-/g, "/")).getDate())); 
}
from = getMidnight(date);
to = getMidnight(to).getTime() + (24 * 3600-1) * 1000;
var event1=getMidnight(new Date(eventdate) + 24 * 3600 * 1000).getTime();   var event2=(new Date(from)).getTime();
var event3=getMidnight(eventdate).getTime();
var event4=(new Date(to)).getTime();
console.log('events',event1,event2,event3,event4);
```

I am trying to print the console message. In the `Chrome` console it displays like shown below.

```
events 1464719400000 1463769000000 1464719400000 1464028199000
```

But on `Safari` browser its not displaying properly and prints like shown below.

```
events NAN 1463769000000 1464719400000 1464028199000
```

It's giving `NAN` in `Safari`. I would like it to print the same in `Safari` as it does in `Chrome`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To make your question easier your problem is with:

```
new Date('2016-06-01 16:48:51')
```

This work okay in chrome but not in safari. The mdn talks about ECMAScript 5 ISO-8601 format support says:

> Alternatively, the date/time string may be in ISO 8601 format. For example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or "2011-10-10T14:48:00" (date and time) can be passed and parsed.
>   If you include T it works:

```
new Date('2016-06-01T16:48:51')
```

You can use new Date('2014-02-18T15:00:48'.replace(/\s/, 'T')).

If you handle a lot of cases like this I will recommend using moment which seems to handle this case very well with or without T: parsing from string. Additionally your whole example is easier with momentjs:

```
var minutes = moment().diff("2014-02-18 15:00:48", 'minutes');
```

Comment: I am not getting any solution from above answer.